# Merging two sorted arrays - why does this NOT work?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, merge, array-merge

I am learning ruby and was given the following assignment:

```
given two sorted arrays like the following we must merge them into one sorted array.
array_1 = [5,8,9,11]
array_2 = [4,6,7,10]

merge(array_1, array_2)

=> [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

Given this brief description, implement the merge method that takes two arrays and returns
 the properly sorted array containing the items from each array.
```

I wrote this answer:

```
def merge(arr1, arr2)
  i = 0
  k = 0
  merged_arr = []
  until k = arr2.count
    while arr1[i] <= arr2[k]
      merged_arr.push(arr1[i])
      i += 1
    end
    merged_arr.push(arr2[k])
    k += 1
 end
 merged_arr
end
```

My instructor sent out a solution, which I understand, however I don't understand why my answer does NOT work. Can someone please explain the faulty logic? Thank you!

Here is the (correct) solution:

```
def merge(array_1, array_2)
    i = 0
    k = 0
    merged_array = []
    while i < array_1.count
        while k < array_2.count && array_1[i] > array_2[k]
            merged_array << array_2[k]                      
            k += 1                                          
        end
        merged_array << array_1[i]
        i += 1                                              
    end
    print merged_array.inspect
 end
```

Comment: what is wrong with `(array_1 + array_2).sort`?

Comment: @BroiSatse It's an exercise, implementing array sort is only a means to learn something so he cannot use built-in sort methods I assume. Though granted this is not clear from the description.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to include that detail - we were not allowed to use any sort method. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BroiSatse: Also, if you have two arrays that you know themselves are already sorted, there are ways to sort them that are faster than appending  them and then using QuickSort.

Answer (score 2):

`k = arr2.count` assigns the value of `arr2.count` to k and evaluates to `k`, so `until k = arr2.count` is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to consider the unequal length of arr1 and arr2, your instructor's solution was only right if arr1.length >= arr2.length, but if arr1.length < arr2.length, then the elements from the extra length was lost in the solution.